# Kinvey ios 3.0 Beta

Tags: ios, beta, kinvey

1) I am trying the new beta version and I tried to setup a DataStore  for querying over User objects. However the User does not support Persistable protocol. I probably can implement the protocol for the User class nevertheless I am not sure whether this is a proper solution. If I subclass User so for MyUser I will have to do protocol implementatio anyway, so is this the correct way?

2) I am missing data relationship. KCSLinkedAppdataStore seems to be gone. Will it be implemented in later versions or is there another mechanism for data relationship in Kinvey 3.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the Kinvey team.

1) Since `User` is a special class it doesn't need to implement the `Persistable` protocol. To get the instance of another user rather than the active user you can use the class function `User.get(userId)`. To perform a query using a `Query` object that will return a list of users is not implemented yet for 3.0, but is in our roadmap.

2) Built-in support for relationships is not implemented in 3.0 for now. We have it in our roadmap to discuss how relationships should be enabled, but as of now, the library doesn't support it.